# What is the equivalent of _bstr_t in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com-interop

I am working on a project where I need to convert C++ code to C#.

I came across `_bstr_t` in the code I would like to know how the equivalent in C#.

Comment: AFAIK, COM string is same as a CLR string

Comment: That'll depend on the context it's used. If it's just to hold data used by the local program logic it can probably replaced with System.string.

Comment: Apply the [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr]) attribute on the argument.

Comment: While the correct definition with a `MarshalAs` attribute is generally the right answer, do you have a specific interface definition you could show that we could work with?  It would help clarify the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`_bstr_t` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx) is a wrapper for the [`BSTR` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This is a string in [OLE Automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation) that is standardized across languages.

That said, the equivalent type in .NET is a [`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx).

The key is when interacting with it (or defining your interfaces for COM interop in .NET code), you'll want to use the [`MarshalAsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx) with a value from the [`UnmanagedType` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) of `UnmanagedType.BStr`, like so:

```
// This is on an interface that is in unmanaged code.
public void DoSomething([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr] string myString);
```

Note that if your class is actually exposing the `_bstr_t` in a COM interface, then you should change it to expose a `BSTR`; `_bstr_t` is a helper class that isn't meant to be exposed across interface boundaries.  The `BSTR` is for that and the methods on `_bstr_t` are for handling the allocation and use of `BSTR` instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just *converting* code, use `string`

If you are *interfacing* with C++ code through PInvoke, you will *probably* declate the parameter as a string and put `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]` in front of the parameter declaration:

```
[DllImport("OldCLib.Dll")]
public static extern void PassBStr([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string s);
```